# Cannot convert value of type 'User?' to expected argument type 'User!'

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, option-type

I suspect there is something wrong with my code, I cannot pinpoint what it is that I am doing wrong here.  The error is on this line here: `self.setUserInfo(firstLastName: firstLastName, user: user, username: username, location: location, biography: biography, password: password, pictureData: pictureData)` which is in my signUp function.

Cannot convert value of type 'User?' to expected argument type 'User!'
[image]

```
func signUP(firstLastName: String, username: String, email: String, location: String, biography: String, password: String, pictureData: NSData!) {

    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
        if error == nil{

           self.setUserInfo(firstLastName: firstLastName, user: user, username: username, location: location, biography: biography, password: password, pictureData: pictureData)

        }else{
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
        }
    }


}

private func setUserInfo(firstLastName: String, user: User!, username: String, location: String, biography: String, password: String, pictureData: NSData!){

    let imagePath = "profileImage\(user.uid)/userPic.jpg"
    let imageRef = storageRef.child(imagePath)

let metaData = StorageMetadata()
    metaData.contentType = "image/jpeg"
    imageRef.putData(pictureData as Data, metadata: metaData){(newMetaData, error)
        in
        if error == nil{
            let changeRequest = User.createProfileChangeRequest()
            changeRequest.displayName = username
            if let photoURL = newMetaData!.downloadURL(){
                changeRequest.photoURL = photoURL

            }
            changeRequest.commitChanges(completion: { (error) in
                if error == nil{

                    self.saveUserInfo(firstLastName: firstLastName, user: user, username: username, location: location, biography: biography, password: password)

                    print("user info set")

                }else{
                    print(error?.localizedDescription)
                }
            })

        }else{
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Show implementation of `Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail:` method

Comment: What does your User class look like?

Answer (score -1):

In the method setUserInfo you've set unwrapped value of User parameter by using "!", but in your auth. completion block it seems that that value is optional.

Here is how you can solve it:

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { [weak self] (user, error) in

    guard let unwrappedError = error, 
          let unwrappedUser = user, 
          let strongSelf = self 
    else {
        print(error?.localizedDescription)
        return
    }

    strongSelf.setUserInfo(firstLastName: firstLastName, user: unwrappedUser, username: username, location: location, biography: biography, password: password, pictureData: pictureData)
}
```

EDIT: I added a strongSelf pattern and used a guard statement, since you were explicitly retaining self here (a no no in network callback closures!), and guard statements are the preferred way to handle a validity check in this scenario because it makes it more clear what your intent is.

Comment: Remove "!" from setUserInfo after declaring the User parameter

Comment: this brought on a bunch of more errors. (image provided)

Comment: Oh, but how did you defined your class where those methods declared? So we will fix the first error. For the second error I've made some change in the guard let statement. As for the third one, I don't see that you removed the "!" from your method declaration private func setUserInfo(firstLastName: String, user: User!, username: String, location: String, biography: String, password: String, pictureData: NSData!). It is still there